# Djangonic way to get second order DB-info in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm messing around with my first Django site and so far it's going good. I am now facing the challenge of getting some information from the DB. My model looks like this:

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country

class OrganisationTypes(models.Model):
    organisation_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisation_type

class Organisations(models.Model):
    organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organisation_type = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationTypes)
    country_of_origin = models.ForeignKey(Countries)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisation_name

class Locations(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisations)
    country_of_location = models.ForeignKey(Countries)
    tel_nr = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s - %s' % (self.organisation, self.country_of_location, self.tel_nr, self.address)
```

I now want to display a list of locations of which I want to display the `organisation_name` and the country_of_origin. To achieve this I wrote the following function:

```
def organisation_locations(requests, organisation_id):
    org = Organisations.objects.get(id=organisation_id)
    location_list = Locations.objects.filter(organisation=organisation_id).order_by('country_of_location')
    output = '<br />'.join([str(loc.organisation)+' from '+str(org.country_of_origin) for loc in location_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

This works correctly, but it doesn't seem like the correct way of doing this. Since the Location table has a foreign key in the Organisations table which in turn has a foreign key in the Countries table I have this vague feeling that Django can do this in one "query" or lookup.

Am I correct in this feeling, or is my way indeed the correct way of doing this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: the query looks ok to me, you just need to change that harcoded html for a proper template

Comment: That query will always return just one element list am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do:

```
location_list = Locations.objects\
                 .filter(organisation=organisation_id)\
                 .order_by('country_of_location')
output = '<br />'.join([str(loc.organisation)+' from '+str(loc.organisation.country_of_origin) for loc in location_list])
```

The *organisation* query isn't necessary. You can access organisation like this: `localization.organisation`.

What is not *Djangonic* in your code is the response. You should have a template and do `return render_to_response` :)

Comment: Thanks for that! Works like a charm! About your suggestion to use templates; I know, but I'm just following the tutorial, and I haven't reached the templates part yet.. ;)